# Ruby cannot find puts and other commands?

Tags: ruby, macos

I was attempting to do what I thought should be a very basic script as my first bit of ruby code. Perhaps someone can help me out with what's going on.

```
./delete_file.rb: line 3: puts: command not found
./delete_file.rb: line 4: auth_token: command not found
./delete_file.rb: line 6: puts: command not found

User1$ cat delete_file.rb 
# /usr/bin/ruby
# Delete file script
puts "Enter current token"
auth_token = gets.chomp

puts "data goes here" + auth_token + "more data here"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first line of file should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: haha, I love it when its simple. thanks :)

Comment: Without the shebang, it tries to execute it as a bash file.

Comment: @Tony, if it was of some help for you please consider to accept it. this is a good practice on stackoverflow :)